# how to calculate total elapsed time

Tags: bash, datetime, ls, date-arithmetic, stat

how to calculate elapsed time based on

start time=

```
[user001a@dev51 logs]# grep 'Recovery Manager' 
refresh_03Jun2019_0250.log|head -1|awk -F'on ' '{print $NF}';
Jun 3 02:50:02 2019
[user001a@dev51 logs]#
```

end time=

```
[user001a@dev51 logs]# ls -l refresh_03Jun2019_0250.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 user001a grp001a 170050 Jun  3 05:06 
refresh_03Jun2019_0250.log
[user001a@dev51 logs]#
```

Note - stat is missing birth time so stat might not be a good option time calculate file create and modify time:

```
[user001a@dev51 logs]# stat refresh_03Jun2019_0250.log
  File: `refresh_03Jun2019_0250.log'
  Size: 170050          Blocks: 344        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 811h/2065d      Inode: 1474545     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  219/  user001a)   Gid: (  219/grp001a)
Access: 2019-06-03 05:06:40.830829026 -0400
Modify: 2019-06-03 05:06:40.827828883 -0400
Change: 2019-06-03 05:06:40.827828883 -0400
[user001a@dev51 logs]#
```

Sample1 output:

```
StartTime=June 3, 2019 at 2:50:02 am
EndTime=June 3, 2019 at 5:06:40 am
ElapsedTime=2 hours, 16 minutes and 38 seconds
```

Sample2 output:

```
ElapsedTime=2 hours, 16 minutes and 38 seconds
```

Comment: See how I formatted [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35728121/1745001) for you so that your code, sample, input, and expected output were all indented 4 chars with blank lines before/after each block? Do the same to this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limitation of this solution: Max 23 hours. For more, days need to be added.

```
StartTime="June 3, 2019 at 2:50:02 am"
EndTime="June 3, 2019 at 5:06:40 am"
StartTimeInEpoch=`echo $StartTime | sed 's/at //g' | date -f- +"%s"`
EndTimeInEpoch=`echo $EndTime | sed 's/at //g' | date -f- +"%s"`
echo $EndTimeInEpoch-$StartTimeInEpoch | bc | sed 's/^/@/g' | date -u -f- "+%_H hours %_M minutes %_S seconds"
```

Output:

```
2 hours 16 minutes 38 seconds
```

Assuming you've got your dates in variables `StartTime` and `EndTime`. It's necessary to remove `at` from them, `sed` do this. Then both dates are converted to epoch time `+"%s"` do the trick. `-f-` tells `date` to take date from stdin (pipe). Then we can subtract the dates, add `@` to the beginning and format with `date`. `-u` mean UTC time - no time shift.